# Java method overload: Does the order of parameter affect latency?

Tags: java, optimization, overloading

Lets say I have following class A with method X. I can overload the methods in the following two ways.

```
A{
  void X(foo p, bar q);
  void X(foo p, baq q);
}

A{
  void X(foo p, bar q);
  void X(baq q, foo p);
}
```

Should the second implementation be preferred since it will take lesser time to resolve and hit the correct function?

Let me know if more clarification is required.

Comment: Your homework for today is: learn the difference between _overriding_ methods and _overloading_ them.

Comment: I sloppily wrote the question, slept over it and totally forgot about the wonderment that I had last night. Thanks for your comment though :)

Comment: Don't drink and ask :P (I'm not implying that you were drunk :P). When you know the difference between these two "things", then it is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of parameters makes no difference as far as the latency is concerned, because overloads based on argument type are resolved at compile time, not at run time.

The decision to call one overload over the other is made after analyzing the context of the call based on static types of parameter expressions. This decision is "recorded" in the byte code, so running JVM does not spend any time making this decision.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter, but you could output a time before and after the call of both functions seperatly and compare the milliseconds.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

System.out.println("Before: {0}", dateFormat.format(date));
x(foo f, baq q);
System.out.println("After: {0}", dateFormat.format(date));
```

If both functions are preforming the same function, which most likley they are seeming as they have the same name, you could just use a generic method.

```
void x(T t, U u){}
```